# cakephp 3.2 $this->Auth->identify() returns false

Tags: cakephp

I did everything for login in cakephp 3.2 but failed to login Auth->identify returns false. I tried with username and email both but its not working.I'm using default password hashing . Please help .

Answer (score 1):

Have You tried to clear Session in browser?
In CakePHP2 I was having problem with Auth - once I was logged in than every time I call Auth->login it returns false because user was already logged.

Comment: Thanks @tomasz n .I have another question if you can help me in that its related to cakephp 2.9 ACL.Could you please check this link and help me out in this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225105/cakephp-2-9-acl-implementation-error